# How can we create Python program which will run even after system shutdown

Tags: python

I have created a Python program which takes 3 to 4 hours to complete its execution when I run it interactively.

Is there any way to run this program in Batch(Background) ?... i.e. Even when I shutdown my machine it will run as expected.

Comment: shutting down entail breaking the electrical circuit, therefore you cant do it. What you might instead want to do is - parallelise (if possible)? What does the program do?

Comment: I think OP just wants the job to continue from the last execution point when the machine is restarted

Comment: You can make it restartable so that it can resume when the computer is turned back on. By using checkpointing.

Comment: When there is no electricity in the board all the logical gates (AND, OR, NOT) will be in low state, so, In simple words you cant perform any operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

I had to read Log file and if any error finds, had to send an email with Error Log.

I have done it through below :

```
- Created a Python program
       : Scheduled it to run every 5 mins
       : Which will scan log file for Error Code
       : If Error Code finds send an email to team with error log
- Deployed program on PCF(Pivotal App Cloud Foundry Server).
- Program runs as per given time frame and works correctly.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use a site like:
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows task scheduler, simply set up time trigger or a startup trigger and the action should be your python file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the program remotely on a server then you may run it via using the & flag, as such

```
python file.py &
```

this keeps the program running even if the terminal is closed, you can also do

```
nohup python file.py &
```

this will write the ouputs(print statements, errors) to nohup.out,

```
nohup python file.py > myout.out &
```

you may do this to redirect this output to any file of your choice, rather than nohup.out

I assume this is what you want, since running a program even if a machine is shut doesn't make sense